# Rails pattern or gem for notifying associations of model changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, observer-pattern

In my app I have a number of issues which fall under the general pattern of:

- Model with association
- Association relies on some property of model and therefore caches it
- Model changes
- Association breaks because cached property is out of date

Is there a specific rails gem or pattern that would allow you to perform something like this on the model:

```
on_change :currency, notify: :booking
```

Then on the association:

```
on_notification :currency, :update_currency
```

Or something along those lines?

I can see that you could do it easily enough with observers or callbacks but would like to DRY this up

Comment: [whisper](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper) is a gem, that provides Pub-Sub capabilities.

Comment: are your associations loaded when you update your Model ?, if so, you could use autosave: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html